# How can I get my keyboard to work during boot again after it was disabled out of the blue?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I have Ubuntu 20.04 dual booted with Windows 10. I had my grub file setup so that I would enter the grub menu upon boot and it has worked fine for weeks. This morning however, I booted on my computer and it skipped the grub menu and my grub settings were changed. I tried changing the settings back to what I had them set to when everything was working fine and it did bring back the grub menu, but introduced my current issue. Here are the settings I put at this point.

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=20

Also uncommented `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`.

These changes did bring back the grub menu, but the issue Im having now was introduced at this point (I believe). MY keyboard stopped working during boot phase. I ran sudo update-grub and sudo apt upgrade. I restarted my computer. The grub menu was back but my keyboard was now disabled until Ubuntu was loaded by the timeout finishing. I cannot enter my BIOS (UEFI) or interact with the grub menu and my keyboard shows no power coming to it at all until the OS is loaded. I undid my changes to the grub file and updated my terminal again, but the keyboard is still not working until the OS is loaded, the grub menu is just skipped now.
Here is the current state of my file etc/default/grub:

```
    # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Not being able to access UEFI settings isn't and can't be related to Grub because that MUST happen BEFORE Grub.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ah okay. I did change some things in the UEFI settings,  Im guessing its that then. Its just strange, because I made changes days ago and the issue just started. If I can enter UEFI somehow Ill post what those settings are.

Comment: Please do not edit the solution in to the question. That's what the answer is for.

Comment: Grub is not showing because `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is set to zero. Therefore, the timeout is at zero seconds which is immediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. As ChanganAuto suggested it wasn`t a grub issue, but I was able to use grub to solve it. Here`s my steps:

Changed the grub settings back to:

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu

GRUB_TIMEOUT=20

so I could at least see the options even if I couldn't interact with them.

Restarted my computer to check the order of possible boot options and noted the position of "UEFI Firmware Settings" which on my system was in position 3 (using a 0 based index, so it was the 4th one shown)

Edited the grub file using the terminal command:

> `cd /etc/default ; sudo vim grub`

Changed the variable GRUB_DEFAULT to 3 to force the system to boot into UEFI instead of UBUNTU without having to select it.

Once I actually got INTO "UEFI Firmware Settings" my keyboard turned on again.

I realized that under Boot Options, I had set the Fast Boot setting to Ultra Fast. I changed this back to disabled, saved my settings, restarted,  and my keyboard powered on with my computer once again!