# How do I get my laptop keyboard to work again?

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, uefi

Hardware: Toshiba Satellite L870-18v

For a few weeks now my laptop keyboard has not worked and I was wondering if there was some way to get it working again. At the moment, I have to use a usb external keyboard which is recognised and works once the O.S. has reached the desktop. However, neither the usb keyboard nor the laptop keyboard work during the BIOS and Grub boot ups.

I thought that I had found an answer at [How can I get my keyboard to work during boot again after it was disabled out of the blue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355089/how-can-i-get-my-keyboard-to-work-during-boot-again-after-it-was-disabled-out-of). I implemented the solution given in the answer on that web page but it did not work. Specifically, adding the line
`GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` to /etc/default/grub, running `sudo update-grub` and then rebooting made absolutely no visible change to the Grub boot screen.

This laptop has UEFI which I have set in the BIOS (i.e. InsydeH20 Setup Utility) to CSM (legacy BIOS) mode as I am more familiar with setting up an hdd to use msdos partitions.

Is there any way of accessing the UEFI in order to get the laptop keyboard working again ?

Stuart

Comment: What kind of a change did you want or expect for the grub menu? If it is currently skipping the grub menu, then you need to increase `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to a value greater than zero. But **do not** set the timeout to negative one `-1` because setting timeout to negative one will disable timeout (essentially setting timeout to an infinite value that will never time out) and since you may not have the ability to input a selection if there is no keyboard, then you wouldn't have a way to proceed past the grub menu.

Comment: I had hoped that including the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` to /etc/default/grub would cause an entry for "UEFI Firmware Settings" to appear in the Grub boot screen (which does appear), as stated in the web page linked to above. I had hoped to use this as a mechanism to force the laptop to boot into the uefi (again as stated in the web page linked to above) thereby allowing me to reset an option in the uefi csm.

Comment: And just to verify, have you tried the repeatedly pressing F2 when you boot and as an alternative, trying F12 to get you to the boot menu where there should be an option to enter bios or uefi mode?

Comment: Also, I seem to remember there was like an fn key option in the BIOS settings that I believe would function independently of your other settings, iirc. Long story short, you might need to press fn and the F key (F2 or F12) at the same time when trying to enter BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: One more thing, it seems like if you disconnect the harddrive then the computer would most likely default to the boot menu or at least give you time to try stuff like unplugging and plugging the external keyboard to try and get it recognized. Just make sure the computer if off if and when you disconnect or reconnect the harddrive and as always, be sure to take [basic static discharge precautions](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/what-is-electro-static-discharge-218791en/#:~:text=Always%20wear%20an%20ESD%20wrist,computer%20before%20handling%20your%20drive.).

Comment: Actually, some sources say to hold down the F2 key (or fn+F2) and power on so that's also worth a try.

Comment: @mchid: Thank you for your replies. Yes, you are correct in that holding down the F2 key and then powering on does take me into the BIOS. (Also, holding down F12 does take me to a boot menu which does not(!) have an entry/selection for UEFI.) However, neither keyboard works whilst "in there". This is the problem. So I need to find a way to somehow get into the CSM of the UEFI in order to re-enable the keyboard. At the moment it looks like I may have to remove/re-insert the CMOS battery in order to reset the BIOS which I want to keep as a very last resort.

Comment: And just to make sure — you did try to unplug and then plug the external keyboard back in after you got in there, right? I had a toshiba satellite after signing in, I always had to unplug the keyboard and plug it back in to recognize it again. Also, there is a setting to enable external keyboard and mouse mentioned [in the manual](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/488661/toshiba-satellite-pro-c870-satellite-c875d-satellite-c875-satellite-c870-e-satellite-l870d-satellite-c870-satellite-l875d-satellite-c870d-satellite-l870-e-satellite-l875-satellite-l870-satellite-pro-l870.html?download)

Comment: But that setting is in the bios settings so kind of hard to get to it now. But since f12 and f2 work to boot, it seems like it's at least recognized at some point. One last thing you might try switching to a different usb port, preferably to one that is a USB2.0 (if there is one) or if you're currently using a usb 2.0 port then try switching to the 3.0 port.

Comment: Just tried unplugging/re-plugging the external keyboard whilst in(!) the BIOS. The external keyboard was still not recognised. Still no response from either keyboard. W.R.T. USB ports: the last time I was properly "in" the BIOS I disabled usb 3.0 support as my web wanderings revealed that, on Linux, usb 3.0 support could sometimes prevent a laptop keyboard from working. So, all usb ports on this system are now usb 2.x

Comment: BTW, thanks for the link to this system's user manual, now downloaded. I always wondered why the hdd was listed as 1 TB yet I could only access 0.5 TB. It appears from the manual that the hdd has a hidden MS Windows recovery section. Maybe I will need to sacrifice my current install of Linux by "recovering" into MS Windows in order to once again have one(!) of the keyboards recognised at boot up and so once again allow change of settings in the BIOS.

Comment: Before that though, maybe there is Grub-related software/modules that I need to install that would allow Grub to recognise one(!) of the keyboards during that phase of the boot up process. I'm now off to research Grub modules, if they exist.